# need to enable a button if the checkbox is enabled using javascript in aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

need to enable a button if the checkbox is enabled using javascript in aspx page. Here is my code in aspx page. Please Help !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkButt(obj) {
    alert("Inside the function");
    document.getElementById('<%=btnLoadForm.ClientID%>').disabled = !obj.checked;
}
```

Comment: Does the checkbox has autopostback set to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnLoadForm.ClientID%>').disabled = !obj.checked;
```

You could try [removing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeAttribute) the `disabled` property from the element (add your logic as needed):

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnLoadForm.ClientID%>').removeAttribute("disabled")
```

Where `disabled` is a Boolean attribute, the value doesn't make much of a difference. You can read more on this in a similar post: [HTML - Why boolean attributes do not have boolean value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089584/html-why-boolean-attributes-does-not-have-boolean-value)

**UPDATE:**

You would need logic around the `removeAttribute` statement. Something similar to:

```
function checkButt(obj) {
    if(obj.checked)
      document.getElementById('<%=btnLoadForm.ClientID%>').removeAttribute("disabled");
}
```

This would enable `document.getElementById('<%=btnLoadForm.ClientID%>')` if `obj.checked` is checked.

Comment: @user1718398 - See if the update above makes things a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code you will get the solution.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function enableordisable() {
            if (document.getElementById('CheckBox1').checked == true) {
                document.getElementById('Button1').disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('Button1').disabled = true;
            }
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="enable" onchange="enableordisable();" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `AutoPostBack="true"`  for the checkbox

Add the event in the script instead of `inline HTML`..

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLoadForm" />
​<asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="chk" />​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**JS**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('chk');

chk.addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('btn').disabled = !this.checked;
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/8sDey/1/)**

Comment: This works

    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnableButton" runat="server" OnClick="checkButt(this)"; Text="I agree" />