# Hidden element of a form array is not getting set in PHP

Tags: php, html

So I've been tasked with crawling through a smallish PHP application to fix bugs and improve things where I can. One thing I noticed was that updates were not updates, they were deletes+inserts, so I'm doing what I can to remedy that.

To that end, I've added a hidden element to each row of a large table of items which will contain the id of said item so that I know what to update. Problem is that it isn't getting set in the items array in `$_POST`, and I haven't any clue why.

As an example, here's a row in HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="c item_index"><sub>1</sub></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="ordered_items[1][id]" id="item_id1" value="9" disabled="">
  <div class="c qty">
    <input type="text" name="ordered_items[1][quantity]" id="quantity1" value="12">
  </div>
  <div class="c vendor_num">
    <input type="text" name="ordered_items[1][vendor_number]" id="vendor_num1" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="c item_desc">
    <input type="text" name="ordered_items[1][description]" id="desc1" value="12">
  </div>
  <div class="c cost_per">
    <input type="text" name="ordered_items[1][cost_per]" id="cost1" value="12.00">
  </div>
  <div class="c total">
    <input type="text" name="ordered_items[1][total]" class="total" placeholder="0.00"
           id="total1" value="144.00" readonly="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's it's entry in `$_POST`:

```
[ordered_items] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [quantity] => 12
                    [vendor_number] => 
                    [description] => 12
                    [cost_per] => 12.00
                    [total] => 144.00
                )

        )
```

I appreciate any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `disabled=""` attribute. Disabled inputs are not submitted when posting.

From the [HTML specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes)

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.
>
> **Note**: The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `disabled=""` attribute in the hidden field.

Comment: `disabled="false"` will still disable it. The way to enable an element is to remove the attribute entirely.

Comment: Thanks, updated answer. Seems like it could work if you do `disabled=false` because `disabled="false"` gets evaluated as true when parsed as a boolean.

Comment: Attributes aren't parsed as booleans. Try it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Isn't the disabled property a boolean property?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089584/html-why-boolean-attributes-do-not-have-boolean-value

Comment: Or better: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes: _The values "true" and "false" are not allowed on boolean attributes. To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted altogether._

Comment: Thanks for the references; makes sense and I learned something!