# How do I add an Rails form helper HTML attribute that does not contain a quoted value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example, "required."

Rails chokes on any attempt to add the attribute thus:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :"ng-model" => "whatever", :class => "form-control input-lg", :"required" %>
```

Comment: Thanks, pjmorse. I was just about to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use boolean values:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :"ng-model" => "whatever", :class => "form-control input-lg", :"required" => true %>
```

Comment: Beat me to it, I was just coming back with [the documentation link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-content_tag).

Comment: Interestingly enough, this outputs required="required" in my HTML. Is this to be expected?

Comment: The magic behind form helpers translates the Ruby constant "true" to the appropriate attribute value according to HTML standards. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089584/html-why-boolean-attributes-do-not-have-boolean-value

Answer (score 1):

You must do the same as you do with class, add `html_attribute => value`

```
<%= f.email_field :email, :"ng-model" => "whatever", :class => "form-control input-lg", :"required" => true %>
```

Comment: I hope it was helpful, :)