# Disable button in pre IE9 without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

How does one disable a button in internet explorer in pre ie9? I tried the following:

```
        var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
        if (button != 'undefined' && button != null)
            button.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Have you tried `button.disabled = 'disabled'`? Why wouldn't it work in <IE9?

Comment: `button != 'undefined'` is always true since `(void 0) != 'undefined'` is true and `document.getElementById` will never return the string `'undefined'`.

Comment: @Kay I see my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML/HTML attribute values are strings, and thus the boolean values "true" and "false" won't be accepted; they have no special meaning

Try it with:

```
var button = document.getElementById('myButton');
if (button != 'undefined' && button != null)
    button.disabled = 'disabled'; //'disabled' not false
```

### Why?

This [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089749/4206206) answer sums it up well, as to *why* you can't use booleans: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7089749/4206206

> In SGML, an attribute may be minimized so that its value alone is short for both the name and the value, with the only possible value for the attribute in this case obviously being the attribute's own name. HTML uses this for boolean attributes, where the presence or absence of the attribute is what's meaningful, and its value is irrelevant.